# LaTeX: UTF8 and algorithm2e clash

Tags: unicode, input-encodings, algorithm2e

I have this input file in utf8 encoding:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\begin{document}

\begin{procedure}
foo
\caption{ö()}
\end{procedure}
\end{document}
```

but this gives me an error:

```
) (./test.aux)
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \unhbox 
l.8 \caption{ö()}
```

somehow the `\caption` command doesn't like the ö character. Is there any way to use ö in utf8 encoding and the algorithm package?

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
inputenc.sty    2008/03/30 v1.1d Input encoding file
    utf8.def    2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
   t1enc.dfu    2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
  ot1enc.dfu    2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
  omsenc.dfu    2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
algorithm2e.sty    2008/00/00 v3.10 algorithms environments
  ifthen.sty    2001/05/26 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
  xspace.sty    2006/05/08 v1.12 Space after command names (DPC,MH)
 relsize.sty    2003/07/04 ver 3.1
```

Comment: Are you using `pdflatex`?

Comment: Yes, and I cannot change easily (well, it's not me that has the problem but a friend, and he's a few days before a deadline and I don't want to tell him "update your TeX installation and do this and that).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Algorithm2e tries to define a command \csname ö\endcsname in your example. The problem is that the "ö" is already a command and - as you are using OT1 font encoding - it contains commands which can't be used in \csname. You can use `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`. This will solve the problem with the ö. But on the whole I do find it rather problematic how algorithm2e defines commands without checking. I would suggest the nokwfunc option.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage%[nokwfunc] % enable it to see the difference
  {algorithm2e}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\section{A}

\begin{procedure}
foo \caption{ö()}
\end{procedure}

\begin{procedure}
foo \caption{section()}
\end{procedure}

\section{B}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I changed to T1 fontenc now anyway but also added the nokwfunc option to the package. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe it is possible to define a macro name with an umlaut and that is what is happening here. Your `\caption{ö()}` will create a command \ö using `csname`. This for example  works perfectly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\begin{document}
\begin{procedure}
\caption{test(disjöint decomposition)}
\end{procedure}
\end{document}
```

The problem is not utf-08 or the umlaut, you just cannot use the umlaut as a macro name.

Comment: Things do work if you switch to a UTF-8 engine (XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX), and load appropriate font support. In the LuaLaTeX case there are some errors due to bad UTF-8 character codes for the 'french' option stuff in `algorithm2e.sty`, but the example file still works.

Comment: Normally I can create a command name with an ö for example. But with `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` (and utf8 input) the ö is a command which probably gets expanded and then fails. In latin 1 this is not a problem as far as I can see.